# Multiple forms using Spring and Spring Roo

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-roo

I am in the process of learning how to use Spring and Spring Roo.  I have a scenario where I want to be able to handle multiple forms on a single page.  My example is to have a single page where the user can update a person's information and address on a single page.  From a data perspective, these are two different entities.

Here's is my view.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<div xmlns:field="urn:jsptagdir:/WEB-INF/tags/form/fields" xmlns:form="urn:jsptagdir:/WEB-INF/tags/form" xmlns:jsp="http://java.sun.com/JSP/Page" version="2.0">
    <jsp:directive.page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8"/>
    <jsp:output omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
    <form:update id="fu_com_demo_demodb_Person" idField="personId" modelAttribute="person" path="/people" versionField="Version" z="lAv+o27QE4hkXQtPdKu/YDmF4fo=">
        <field:simple field="addresses" id="c_com_demo_demodb_Person_addresses" messageCode="entity_reference_not_managed" messageCodeAttribute="Address" z="Qv+QHD5RorE8Zaf6FDT4MO0J55k="/>
        <field:input field="firstName" id="c_com_demo_demodb_Person_firstName" z="vS8EgEHhso2KgUrCIomUBqF4QLI="/>
        <field:input field="lastName" id="c_com_demo_demodb_Person_lastName" z="w0qweGLAQxRPJxxAehZxWpoaVsg="/>
        <field:input field="middleName" id="c_com_demo_demodb_Person_middleName" z="5cuoVeM25fLeZP1PnBA/9Dh13xE="/>
    </form:update>
    <form:update id="fu_com_demo_demodb_Address" idField="addressId" modelAttribute="address" path="/addresses" versionField="Version" z="QH/Ew5OSBOxqFzEqNt6Y/qpjF8g=">
        <field:select field="personId" id="c_com_demo_demodb_Address_personId" itemValue="personId" items="${people}" path="/people" z="ljx4bVEfoA3j/ChDMHPhkKZM4tc="/>
        <field:input field="line1" id="c_com_demo_demodb_Address_line1" z="VzcJoyGz+Kg9YCf9RPzbQ7IYkbk="/>
        <field:input field="line2" id="c_com_demo_demodb_Address_line2" z="FxoV1g01MRUJhNNHGyR2obbr1z8="/>
        <field:input field="city" id="c_com_demo_demodb_Address_city" z="nFaz+RzSUsjxA6pj7O4p6K4Q+2U="/>
        <field:input field="state" id="c_com_demo_demodb_Address_state" z="idFpXGWkGZvlVI/YOk46rXRu2ZA="/>
        <field:input field="zipCode" id="c_com_demo_demodb_Address_zipCode" z="sKg1vzHjd5yi/EjhvwI1iXlVY7c="/>
    </form:update>
</div>
```

What I have not been able to figure out is how to create a controller that can properly handle the view above.  I am not sure what to do with @RooWebScaffold and @RequestMapping.

Any suggestions or assistance would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way is to let Roo generate the controller for person update. Then copy the created controller method (updateForm) from the ?_Roo_Controller.aj file in the controller class (Use the "Push In" Refactoring in the Outline View of the AspectJ file.)).

Roo will recognize that and remove the updateForm method from the aj file.

Then you can enhance the method like you want.

---

Anyway with your Two-Form-Page you are leaving the support of Roo. So it is may better and cleaner to let roo generate the Controller Class and the jspx and then  disable the roo support for THIS controller. (Run "Push In" and the remove `@RooWebScaffold` annotation) Roo Will delete the ?_Roo_Controller.aj file.

But do not delete the `@RequestMapping` annotation, it is part of Spring-MVC (not of Roo).

Comment: Thanks Ralph for the answer and Tanin for the question. I think this part of Roo development is not easy to find, even in the official documentation.

Answer (score 0):

As Ralph described you need to push-in the createForm-method first.

Then duplicate the addAttribute-line and change the entity like in the following code:

```
@RequestMapping(params = "form", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String createForm(Model uiModel) {
    uiModel.addAttribute("person", new Person());
    uiModel.addAttribute("address", new Address());
    return "person/update";
}
```

Your view should work now.